# Convert Userscript to unpacked Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I was just wondering if there was any real easy way to go from a userscript that I have loaded in *Scriptish* to an unpacked extension in Chrome. I understand the hierarchy and the need for a manifest.json when dealing with an unpacked extension but I'm confused how to go between each other. I have a basic userscript that looks like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             Random text field filler
// @include        https://websitehere.com
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("check box").checked = false;
waitForKeyElements ("[id='home_country']", myCountry);

function myCountry (jNode) {
    var node = jNode[0];
    for (var J = node.options.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
        if (node.options[J].text==('US')) {
            node.selectedIndex = J;
            break;
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('first_name').value="John"
document.getElementById('last_name').value="Doe"
```

This just selects US as a country from a dropdown and fills in some text fields on a website with names. How would I make this into something I could use in Chrome? I make use of the waitForKeyElements() function and am not sure if I can have that capability carry over. I was thinking of including the jquery.min and waitforkeyelements js files somehow in the manifest json. Is this possible? Any help or insight would be a great help.
Thank you!

EDIT:

This is a simple demonstration of what I have going on. I'm just trying to get the text field's value to be my email on a checkout process. I'm also showing the logic I have for choosing the US as the country in the drop down box. This all works in Mozilla's add-ons.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your content script's code should always be injected, register it in the extension manifest using the `content_scripts` field, as in the following example.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have the manifest actually setup as such but it's not firing when on the website. I pass the two aforementioned delimiters and both files are in the source folder. I'll edit my post and show an example.

Comment: I'm missing it. Is it the asterisk and dot prior to the address? I removed that and it still didn't fire. =/ I just now noticed in the console that the waitForKeyElements() function isn't being recognized. This is defined in the file along side of the other .js and .json in the folder.

Comment: put `waitforkeyelements.js` first in array